# the data didn't save on firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frontend

I am working on react and build the burger application. 
This is the code (call function) for the database:

```
    orderHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();        
        this.setState({Loading: true});
        console.log(this.props.ingrediants);
        const order = {
            ingrediants : this.props.ingrediants,
            Price : this.props.price,
            customers : {
                Name: 'Zulfiqar Hussain Anjum',
                address: {
                    street: '4',
                    zipcode: '46000', 
                    Country: 'Pakistan',
                },
                email: 'raeesanjum010@gmail.com'
            },
            deliveryMethod: 'fastest',
        }
        axios.post('/orders.json', order)
        .then(response=> {
            this.setState({Loading: false});
            this.props.history.push('/');
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            this.setState({Loading: false});
        });
    }
```

After putting the data the ingredients didn't show on the database but the customer and price will be saved on the database... The below code is the data which is saved on the database.

```
burger-react-app-2faba
ingrediants
orders
-M-BFmWZ3X73P7ToBMyb
Price: 
"6.500000000000001"
customers
deliveryMethod: 
"fastest"
```

Comment: please share your server code.

Comment: I am not using any backend API, I am getting the data from firebase URL

Comment: so you're saying that this line: `axios.post('/orders.json', order)` is for calling Firebase??

Comment: yes, brother, i am calling firebase through axios.post

Comment: I don't think you're understanding your code well. `'/orders.json'` is not a Firebase URL. it's some URL to your local express server. look at the code and post it.

Comment: brother this is the base URL "https://burger-react-app-2faba.firebaseio.com/"